# Method with kwargs

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I get error when I want to use  this style.

```
User.objects().update(kwargs)
```

How can I do it?

P.S
This style working good

```
User.objects().update(state=1)
```

Comment: try: `User.objects().update(**kwargs)`

Comment: Did you mean `.update(**kwargs)`? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Comment: I have method which getting `**kwargs`, but when I want use it in `update` method, it throw error 'TypeError: upsert must be True or False'

Comment: Well then make sure `kwargs['upsert']` is either `True` or `False`. Dictionary unpacking doesn't automatically save you from passing invalid parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [unpack the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters):

```
User.objects().update(**kwargs)
```

Credit to @jonrsharpe for the appropriate question link.